# How to get isoCode form GeoLite2?

Tags: php, geoip, maxmind

I have a GeoLite2 from MaxMind installed and the test php file:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use MaxMind\Db\Reader;
$ipAddress = '8.8.8.8';
$databaseFile = './GeoLite2-Country.mmdb';

$reader = new Reader($databaseFile);

print_r($reader->get($ipAddress));

$reader->close();
```

Gives me these results:

```
Array ( [continent] => Array ( [code] => NA [geoname_id] => 6255149 [names] => Array ( [de] => Nordamerika [en] => North America [es] => NorteamÃ©rica [fr] => AmÃ©rique du Nord [ja] => åŒ—ã‚¢ãƒ¡ãƒªã‚« [pt-BR] => AmÃ©rica do Norte [ru] => Ð¡ÐµÐ²ÐµÑ€Ð½Ð°Ñ ÐÐ¼ÐµÑ€Ð¸ÐºÐ° [zh-CN] => åŒ—ç¾Žæ´² ) ) [country] => Array ( [geoname_id] => 6252001 [iso_code] => US [names] => Array ( [de] => USA [en] => United States [es] => Estados Unidos [fr] => Ã‰tats-Unis [ja] => ã‚¢ãƒ¡ãƒªã‚«åˆè¡†å›½ [pt-BR] => Estados Unidos [ru] => Ð¡Ð¨Ð [zh-CN] => ç¾Žå›½ ) ) [registered_country] => Array ( [geoname_id] => 6252001 [iso_code] => US [names] => Array ( [de] => USA [en] => United States [es] => Estados Unidos [fr] => Ã‰tats-Unis [ja] => ã‚¢ãƒ¡ãƒªã‚«åˆè¡†å›½ [pt-BR] => Estados Unidos [ru] => Ð¡Ð¨Ð [zh-CN] => ç¾Žå›½ ) ) )
```

What I need is just the isoCode (in this case US), anyone know how to get just "US" from GeoLite2 not that whole Array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way [MaxMind's database reader](https://github.com/maxmind/MaxMind-DB-Reader-php) is designed; it always returns the full record for every lookup.

You can get the specific piece of information you're interested in by accessing elements of the returned array directly:

```
// Fetch the database record for this IP address
$record = $reader->get($ipAddress);

// Output just the ISO country code ("US", in this case)
echo $record['country']['iso_code'] . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Thank you Simon I thought yo can just ask for iso_code.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your example:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use MaxMind\Db\Reader;
$ipAddress = '8.8.8.8';
$databaseFile = './GeoLite2-Country.mmdb';

$reader = new Reader($databaseFile);

$record = $reader->get($ipAddress);

print($record['country']['iso_code']);

$reader->close();
```

Or using the [GeoIp2 API](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php):

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;


$reader = new Reader('/usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIP2-City.mmdb');


$record = $reader->city('8.8.8.8');
print($record->country->isoCode);
```